# Iframe CSS Properties

Tags: javascript

I am using iframe with design mode on like textbox (The Richtextarea Concept) and which changes i am making in iframe that will affect in the div. but there will be only text changes no Image.

How to do this  Because the changes will be done in this iframe only but can not be seen to user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this:

[Inter-Frame Communication with Javascript](http://cross-browser.com/talk/inter-frame_comm.html)